# 500 error after migrating from Easy Apache 3 to EA4 on Centos6 VPS

Tags: web-hosting, htaccess, html, apache

I made the mistake of clicking the button in WHM to migrate from Easy Apache 3 to EA4 and now I am receiving a 500 error when I try to visit my site. What have I broken and how can I troubleshoot the problem? I have tried restarting httpd and restarting the server. I checked the .htaccess file and it is still in place. I am running Apache 2.4 on a Centos6 server platform.

Comment: This is way beyond what we can help with.  You need to contact your web host.

Comment: Check your servers error log for the details of this error. What directives do you have in your server config / `.htaccess`?

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks -- the log showed a particular file to be "writeable by group." When I changed the permissions to 644 as recommended for PHP files in another forum post I found the issue apparently resolved as the site is now available. Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad you got it sorted. If you can add that as an "answer" below (and later accept it) it will remove the quest from the unanswered question queue and perhaps help other readers in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checked error logs using:

```
tail /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log
```

Logs indicated "SoftException in Application.cpp:267: File "/home/*mywebsite*/public_html/*myfile*.php" is writeable by group

A web search revealed an article [here](https://my.getstarted.com.au/knowledgebase/56/500-Error-File-is-writeable-by-group.html) with this suggestion:

> This
>   is due to the server running SuPHP and the files having higher
>   permissions than allowed, to fix this problem you need to make sure
>   your files are chmod 644 for all PHP based files and 755 for
>   directories in order for them to work with SuPHP.You can easily do
>   this by connecting via FTP with Filezilla and right clicking on the
>   problem folders and files and selecting file permissions.

I changed the permissions on the problem file from 664 to 644 and the problem was resolved.